# How to connect to sql server from php desktop

Tags: sql-server, phpdesktop

My application run smoothly on wamp but when I tried to convert it to desktop application using phpdesktop, this error was displayed on the screen **could not find driver**

I have already done this in ini.php in phpdesktop folder

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
```

And I have copied the extensions to the ext folder

Comment: You cannot load both NTS and TS versions of extensions at the same time. Try one and then the other one.